# How to on/off LED in android not flash light?

Tags: android, android-camera, led

I am trying to on/off LED on button click. But according to [this](http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2009/09/tutorial-how-to-use-led-with-android.html) , it works with notification. I have tried and it is working with notification. I want to on/off LED without notification. So far what I have tried is below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
            .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL|Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    noti.ledARGB = Color.RED;

    noti.ledOnMS = 100;
    noti.ledOffMS = 100;
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

It is working when screen is off and I have run application. Can someone help me doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: can you able to post what you have tried?

Comment: The above code is using in notification and it is working as per your question, what you tried without notification.

Comment: I have not get any other way to do this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any APIs for dealing with the LEDs other than the Notification class, because it's inbuilt and those are totally handled by hardware based so only **Notification class** can handle it.So please don't waste your time to searching about it.

Hope you understand it.

Comment: I have got it one or two places but I have required it for bar-code scanner.

Comment: so you need to use Notification class only those only provide to handle it.So please closed your question because no any other solutions.